# Help with producing sketch of 3D floor function

Tags: graphing-functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to find a software that I can use to produce a sketch of the function as follows: 
$$\zeta({x,y})=\frac{\lfloor{\sqrt[y]{x}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{x}{y}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\frac{\sqrt[y]{x}}{y}\rfloor}}{x}$$ 
I've tried using Wolfram alpha but, no result comes up, is it too much data to compute?
I can get away with keeping the first term as floor function, but not the other two.

Comment: How about you try this in wolfram alpha: simplify your function by leaving out some terms, or removing the floor functions etc. Then slowly add more and more detail until you catch the point where it breaks.

Comment: I can manage to get away with one floor function, I think if I look at the function without the floor functions over a large x,y domain it should be similar-is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure. Which floor function can you get away with? The first, second or third term in the numerator? Please add this info to the question so we can help you as best we can

Comment: Added to question

Comment: are $x$ and $y$ positive reals ?

Comment: Because of the floor,  the numerator has abrupt changes and quite irregular because of the exponentiation: computer programs have difficulties to render it as a surface.

Comment: Have you tried all possible combinations of floor functions turned on/off? There are $3$ floor functions so $2^3 = 8$ possible subsets covering all usages of floor. Have you tried all of these? Could you list in your question which of these work and which don't? After that, could you try either zoom out i.e. make the range you're plotting larger or else multiply every x and y value by a constant such as 1000, which would effectively zoom out. You could also try the opposite: zooming in. Could you add all your findings to the question? Thanks